# How to create Double spacing single column in IEEEtrans template

Tags: formatting

I am using IEEEtrans template for  writing an article. I have prepared the document which is double column single spacing IEEE format.  However, as per journal guidelines I also need to upload the manuscript in double-spaced single-column (12 point font)format in pdf. How can  I do that using the same template?

Answer (score 30):

I used following options for by documentclass and it worked:

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,onecolumn,draftclsnofoot,]{IEEEtran}
```

Comment: I'm currently in the same situation as @Ehsa. These options indeed make the document single-column, however, the spacing does not seem to change to double-spacing.

Answer (score 7):

As @Ehsa mentioned:

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,onecolumn,draftclsnofoot,]{IEEEtran}
```

Where:

- 12pt: is the font size,
- onecolumn: is to set the number of columns to 1,
- draftclsnofoot: is to set the document to "draft" mode, by setting double line spacing and 1 inch margin from all four sides. This format is designed to let reviewers have some space (between lines) to add comments, and that is why it has the word "draft" in it. The other options are "draft", "draftcls", and "final".

(Source: section B in [IEEEtran class documentation](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf))